# How can I create a .pem file using M2Crypto?

Tags: python, openssl, m2crypto

I would like to reproduce this command using python.
$ openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -x509 -days 365 -out key2.pem

NOTE: calling the openssl binary directly is not a nice solution.

Comment: You could look into [pyOpenSSL][http://packages.python.org/pyOpenSSL/]. Although I don't particularly see anything wrong with just calling the command directly.

Comment: Our product's installer calls the openssl executable to create the cert we need.  It does the job.